# remove an element from dom in react so as to make another z index element clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a header div and alert div in my app. The alert div has a `z-index` of 2 to stack on the front on the header, so as to show notifications inside it.

However, this is making the header div unclickable. Both header and alert divs are positioned absolutely.

Alert is overlayed to the right of the header on top of it.

New to React. In angular would do with `*ngIf` (or) set the display to none on alert div when the notifications array length is zero or null.

Not sure how to do here.

index.jsx

```
    <div className={classname('aclass', 'bclass')}>
      <div classname={styles.notificationWrapper}>
        {this.notificationArray.map( (alert) => ( 
           <pxAlert 
              visible
              classes={classnames(style.aert, 'alert'}>
           </pxalert>
         )
        )}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with an [inline if with logical && operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator):

```
    <div className={classname('aclass', 'bclass')}>
      <div classname={styles.notificationWrapper}>
        {this.notificationArray && this.notificationArray.map( (alert) => ( 
           <pxAlert 
              visible
              classes={classnames(style.aert, 'alert'}>
           </pxalert>
         )
        )}
      </div>
```

Hope this helps,